# Include math.js to Google Sheets JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, math.js

I would like to use math.js functions in Google Sheets script editor. How can I make math.js accessible?

Comment: Transpile it to a js1.6 compatible Apps Script library. Eval a remote url. Use a sidebar/modal with `HtmlService`, and import it there like in a browser. Too many ways to get an actual useful answer from your broad question.

Comment: There's a official [api](http://api.mathjs.org/) too.

Comment: The uncompressed mathjs file is 65 thousand lines long.  [Mathjs link](https://unpkg.com/mathjs@5.2.0/dist/math.js)  I'm not sure how the Apps Script code editor would handle that being pasted into a file.  It looks like the Mathjs code uses the `find` method, which the current JavaScript version in Apps Script doesn't have.  It could be a lot of work to try to use the code directly in Apps Script.

Comment: Capitalize math --> Math.whatever works.  MATH.whatever and math.whatever do not. Speaking from experience